# xcodebuild fails through Jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins, ios-provisioning

We have been doing CI builds through Jenkins.  I did not set up Jenkins so I can't answer questions about how its set up.

We are adding a WatchKit extension.  We are following these steps https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1814/_index.html to switch from specifing the provisioning profile to switching to automatic.

The build command fails through Jenkins, but if I run the command from the command line, it works.  I think both are using the same user.  The distribution certificate is in the login keychain and the system keychain.

Our command is

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -target "mobile" -sdk "iphoneos8.3" -scheme "mobile" clean archive
```

The error we get is like this for each extension and application:

```
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “XXXXXXXXXX” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'
```

Any advice how to fix or troubleshoot this error?

Comment: For the successful run from the command line, are you running the xcodebuild command from the Jenkins machine, or from your local machine?  If they are two different machines, it is most likely that the certificate and provisioning profile that includes the WatchKit extension app ids.  Also, did iOS builds ever work on the Jenkins instance?

Comment: The xcodebuild commands works on the build server from the command line, but not in our script that the Jenkins job runs.  The change that broke our Jenkins build is that we used to say in our project file which provisioning profile to use.  I was told by an Apple engineer that is the old way, and the new way is to just use Automatic.  (See Technical Q&A QA1814)  Using Automatic breaks the Jenkins build; I "fixed" it by going back to the old way.  But with not using Automatic, I'm getting errors when building a development build for testing our Apple Watch extension.

Comment: OK,  recently switched to using Automatic, but we aren't doing an Apple Watch.  You do need to make sure you have the same certificate and provisioning profiles installed on both the build machine and the developer Macs.  We fixed a lot of issues by making a script the the developers could run to keep the provisioning profiles in sync.

Comment: It works on the build server, just not when ran through a Jenkins job.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the command the same from the command line as the Jenkins job is.  You'll need to look at the Jenkins command console output to see the exact xcodebuild command.  Is the build config the same for each?  Also, is Jenkins running under a different user ID?  If so, that could cause the issue since different user accounts have different keychains.

Comment: I have jenkins Master running on Aws instance of Ubuntu and created mac laptop as slave , when I run using xcode in mac loptop build is successful but when I trigger it from jenkins its giving error : Check dependencies
No profiles for 'com.patientportal.patientportal360' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.patientportal.patientportal360'.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
 Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the certificates you required in your Keychain. Move them from **Login** to **System**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Jenkins profile management plugin & adding prov and then compile using XCBuild.

Comment: How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

When I execute the following command via `Execute Shell`, I am able to run `xcodebuild`:

```
security unlock-keychain -p ${OSPASSWORD} ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db && xcodebuild -scheme ${XCODE_SCHEME} -sdk ${XCODE_SDK} -archivePath \"build\" -configuration Release archive
```

Hope it helps.